# Change starting page in app created with Windows Template Studio

Tags: c#, uwp

I created an app with Windows Template Studio on Visual Studio 2017.
The app is mainly a `NavigationDrawer` with different pages.

Everything was ok, until I wanted to add a login page.

So I created the `XAML` of the login page, etc. But now I want it to show before the `NavigationDrawer` page on app startup.

I seeked some documentation about the `App.xaml.cs` to know what to change to do that but, because of the use of Windows Template Studio, the code is not really vanilla anymore.

I tried a few things and the only thing I'm able to do right now is to change the shell page of the `NavigationDrawer` to my `Login` page. 
That's not exactly what I want because my first intention was to make the app unavailable until you log in, and because the `NavigationDrawer` is still usable the user can still do what he wants to.

My `app.xaml.cs` looks like this :

```cs
using System;

using BasePosteMobilite.Services;

using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace BasePosteMobilite
{
    public sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        private Lazy<ActivationService> _activationService;

        private ActivationService ActivationService
        {
            get { return _activationService.Value; }
        }

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Deferred execution until used. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx for further info on Lazy<T> class.
            _activationService = new Lazy<ActivationService>(CreateActivationService);
        }

        protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!args.PrelaunchActivated)
            {
                await ActivationService.ActivateAsync(args);
            }
        }

        protected override async void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            await ActivationService.ActivateAsync(args);
        }

        private ActivationService CreateActivationService()
        {
            return new ActivationService(this, typeof(ViewModels.LoginViewModel), new Lazy<UIElement>(CreateShell));
        }

        private UIElement CreateShell()
        {
            return new Views.ShellPage();
        }
    }
}
```

ShellPage.xaml.cs :

```cs
using System;

using BasePosteMobilite.ViewModels;

using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace BasePosteMobilite.Views
{
    // TODO WTS: Change the icons and titles for all NavigationViewItems in ShellPage.xaml.
    public sealed partial class ShellPage : Page
    {
        private ShellViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return ViewModelLocator.Current.ShellViewModel; }
        }

        public ShellPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = ViewModel;
            ViewModel.Initialize(shellFrame, navigationView, KeyboardAccelerators);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.Initialize :

```cs
public void Initialize(Frame frame, WinUI.NavigationView navigationView, IList<KeyboardAccelerator> keyboardAccelerators)
{
    _navigationView = navigationView;
    _keyboardAccelerators = keyboardAccelerators;
    NavigationService.Frame = frame;
    NavigationService.NavigationFailed += Frame_NavigationFailed;
    NavigationService.Navigated += Frame_Navigated;
    _navigationView.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a project with login required feature and you will see the following code from ActivateAsync method:

```
 var silentLoginSuccess = await IdentityService.AcquireTokenSilentAsync();
            if (!silentLoginSuccess || !IdentityService.IsAuthorized())
            {
                await RedirectLoginPageAsync();
            }
```

That's it. If you want to redirect to your own page, write the detectation code under ActivationService.ActivateAsync(args) method. If you see the customer is not logged in. Call redirect login method. Here is the code from template studio about redirectlogin:

```
  public async Task RedirectLoginPageAsync()
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        NavigationService.Frame = frame;
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        await ThemeSelectorService.SetRequestedThemeAsync();
        NavigationService.Navigate<Views.LogInPage>();
    }
```